# How to set the initial value for a Qt stylesheet property

Tags: css, qt

For the following stylesheet snippet I can set the value of `mode` from code using the widget's `setProperty` method. How can I set its initial value in the stylesheet itself?

```
QPushButton[mode="large"] {
    font-size: 30px;
}

QPushButton[mode="small"] {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the id of the button you can set it just like you would in any stylesheet

e.g.

```
QPushButton#menuButton1 {
    background-color: red;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: beige;
    font: bold 14px;
    min-width: 10em;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

[Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, but I think what you might be saying is that instead of setting the initial value of the property "mode" I can set the initial value of value of font-size instead.

Comment: thats exactly what i meant is that not what you asked? maybe i misunderstood